# DJANGO - NoReverseMatch at / (index;)

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm try to set the **get_absolute_path** and I've been trying to define the regex's URL for profile.html page to show the details of user.

models.py (app users):

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.


class UserGroup(models.Model):
    GROUP_CHOICE = (
        ('Administrator JAM', 'Administrator JAM'),
        ('Supervisors', 'Supervisors'),
        ('Agents', 'Agents'),
    )

    name = models.CharField('User Group Name', max_length=50, unique=True, choices=GROUP_CHOICE)
    slug = models.SlugField('Group ID', unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User's Group"
        verbose_name_plural = "User's Groups"
        ordering = ['name']  # ordenando por nome e depois por ultima modificação


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
    username_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[\w_-]{5,50}$', message='The username must be consist only of letters and numbers. From 5 up to 15 characters allowed.')
    username = models.CharField('Username', validators=[username_regex], max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField('User ID', max_length=50)
    user_group = models.ForeignKey('users.UserGroup', verbose_name='User Group')
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True, choices=((True, 'Active'), (False, 'Deactive')))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_agent', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
        ordering = ['name', 'user_group', 'is_active']
```

urls.py (from root):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name="edit_profile"),
    url(r'^inbox/$', views.inbox, name="inbox"),
    url(r'^profile/', include('users.urls', namespace='users'))
]
```

urls.py (from app users):

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.profile_agent, name='profile_agent'),
]
```

where that I'm trying to get the aboslute URL, it's from the *index.html*:

```
<!-- Sidebar user nav -->
<nav class="sidebar-user__nav">
    <ul class="sidebar__nav">
        <li>
            <a href="{% url agent.get_absolute_url %}"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'inbox' %}"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Inbox</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: Error Page Django]

When I try to access page:
[image]

Anyone have some idea of because I'm getting the error?

Before everything, I'm appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the namespace `users` when you call `reverse`.

```
return reverse('users:profile_agent', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

In the template, you don't need to use the URL tag when using `get_absolute_url`.

```
{{ agent.get_absolute_url }}
```

In the url pattern, you should escape the hyphen `[\-\w]+`, or move it to the end `[\w-]+`.